# why use unique magic number in defining ioctl

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

I was wondering why we need to define a unique magic number while creating ioctl commands. As the ioctl function in the kernel will be executed using the device file descriptor and inode linkage in the vfs, so there won't be any case where an ioctl will be misfired to a different device as it is binded by the file descriptor. Even if the user makes a gaffe and triggers ioctl to a different file descriptor, how will "having unique magic numbers" avoid that.

From the text I read about this:
"Programmers much choose a number for the integer command representing each command implemented through ioctl. The number should be unique across the system. Picking arbitrary number is a bad idea, because: **Two device nodes may have the same major number. An application could open more than one device and mix up the file descriptors, thereby sending the right command to the wrong device.** Sending wrong ioctl commands can have catastrophic consequences, including damage to hardware. A unique magic number should be encoded into the commands with one of the following macros

Text source: http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc440/labs/lab06.pdf

Comment: Please give a source for "the text" so that its author may be properly dealt with.

Comment: Assume there are **two devices** - A and B - and they both support **same ioctl number** NA, but for different jobs, `jobA` and `jobB`. Assume there is an application which opens devices A for perfom `jobA` and opens device B for some other purpose. But application may **accidentally** call that ioctl with the number NA for the wrong descriptor, B instead of A. In that case `jobB` has been performed, which is unexpected by the application. Would device B support some other ioctl number instead, calling `ioctl(B, NA)` will return an error code. This is exactly what the bolded text tells you.

Comment: "*Why use ...*" -- In a perfect world where everyone wrote perfect code with no bugs, such defensive schemes would not be necessary. But it's not a perfect world. So a simple scheme with no performance penalty can detect an improper directive argument with zero cost.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You mean, 2 devices controlled by the same driver right ? since ioctls are defined per driver and not per device. Also, then how can the same ioctl humber be defined for 2 different jobs if they belong to the same driver (although controlling different devices), can you pls give example.

Comment: "You mean, 2 devices controlled by the same driver right?" - No, I mean 2 devices, controlled by two **independent drivers**, doing different jobs. And those drivers choose accidentally the same ioctl number for perform these jobs. Say, the first driver uses ioctl for manage sound volume, and the second driver uses ioctl for manage CPU speed. You don't want to burn you CPU just because the application instead of increasing a sound volume twice would increase CPU speed, do you?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I got what you are saying, thank you.

Comment: Using a magic number is possible to stack more drivers on the same device, consider a TCP stack for example.  Keep in mind that these methods are a quick and dirty way to code a number of functions at the expense of type safety.